# Why do GCP functions deployed without docker have images in Container Registry?

Tags: firebase, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I recently joined a new project where Firebase functions are deployed using the `firebase deploy` command. However, upon checking the Google Cloud Platform Container Registry, I noticed Docker images corresponding to these function deployments. Strangely, the project owner claims they don't utilize Docker, and there are no Docker YAML files in the repository. How could the Firebase function deployments end up in the Container Registry without explicit Docker usage? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions deployments are all docker images.  When you deploy a function, GCP automatically creates a docker image for your function code and the chosen runtime.

You should review the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building) for more detail:

> When you deploy your function's source code to Cloud Functions, that source is stored in a Cloud Storage bucket. Cloud Build then automatically builds your code into a container image and pushes that image to a image registry. Cloud Functions accesses this image when it needs to run the container to execute your function.

Comment: I see, so if it's done automatically by GCP, how do I Transition to Artifact Registry? Will GCP do the transition automatically?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  When you use Cloud Functions, you accept that GCP will do all the work.  There is no transitioning.  If you want to do something different with your code, then don't deploy with Cloud Functions at all, and build and deploy your own docker container using different products.

Comment: when I check container registry page I see a notice that says Container Registry will be deprecated, transition to Artifact Registry. As I'm not the one storing docker images in container registry in the first place, how do I transition?(there is no explanation provided in the docs), or will GCP store images in Artifact Registry automatically?

Comment: Since GCP is automatically doing all the required work for your Cloud Functions deployments, I think you can assume that it will continue to work no matter what.  You don't have to do anything.  If something stops working with your deployment using the Firebase CLI, then contact Firebase support.

Comment: Emails about the move to Artifact Registry started going out in the past couple of days.  As @DougStevenson suggests: there's nothing required to be done by you, unless you want to adopt the migration to AR sooner rather than later.

Comment: @GregFenton I hope you are right. The email I got says "If you use Container Registry transitively through... Cloud Functions, upgrade to Artifact Registry using repositories with gcr.io support to ensure that your workflows continue to function." When I click on the instructions to do that, all the gcloud gobbledegook (roles, permissions, and product names) is totally impossible for a simple "firebase deploy" user to understand.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned, GCP *used to* create the source code image in **Container Image** by default. Now that Container Image is going to be retired, the default option to host the image is **Artifact Registry**, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--docker-registry):

> Docker Registry to use for storing the function's Docker images. The option artifact-registry is used by default.

> Warning: Artifact Registry and Container Registry have different image storage costs. For more details, please see https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#deployment_costs.

> DOCKER_REGISTRY must be one of: artifact-registry, container-registry.

Now, if you need to **migrate the Cloud Function image to Artifact Registry**, you can re-deploy the CF with the tag:

```
--docker-registry=artifact-registry
```

- For CF gen 1: re-deploy by setting the tag --docker-registry=artifact-registry
- For CF gen 2: no action required, Artifact Registry is supported out of the box according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building#image_registry).